# Finding all unassociated labels in the ASP.NET project

Tags: visual-studio-2012, resharper

I'm undertaking a Section 508 upgrade/conversion/whatever, and one thing that would speed me up a lot is an easy TODO list.  A large offender is that we have <asp:label> tags without the `AssociatedControlID=""` attribute set.  How can I easily find all of these tags in my solution?

I'm using Visual Studio 2012 with ReSharper (can a custom pattern help?).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, a custom pattern should be able to find those for you. Use ReSharper → Find → Search with Pattern, and set up the pattern something like:

```
<asp:label $attributes$ />
```

where the `$attributes$` placeholder is an "attribute placeholder", with the option "Name should NOT match the regex" set to something like `\bAssociatedControlID\b`.